# How to change all CSS file into SCSS

Tags: css, ruby, shell

I want to change all `css` file into `scss` in my Rails project.

The folder structure is unpredictable, like

```
stylesheets - A     - A_1   - a_1.css
            - B     - B.css
            - C     - C_1   - c_1_1    - c_1_1.css
                    - C_2   - c-2.css
            - d.css
```

I wrote some code, but it can only make a `css` file which is in `./stylesheets` become `scss`:

```
require 'fileutils'

Dir.chdir('app/assets/stylesheets')
Dir.glob('./*.css').each do |f|
    puts f
  FileUtils.mv f, "#{File.basename(f,'.*')}.scss"
end
```

If there is a better way like a shell script it is also acceptable.

---

Thanks to @maxpleaner, I modified it into this:

```
require 'fileutils'

Dir.chdir('app/assets/stylesheets')

Dir.glob("./**/*.css").each do |path|
    #p path
    FileUtils.mv path, "#{File.dirname(path)}/" + "#{File.basename(path,'.*')}.scss"
end
```

and it works fine.

Comment: Ruby's [Dir](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Dir.html) class can help you recursively descend into a hierarchy but it tends to waste CPU and RAM resources. I'd recommend reading the documentation for Ruby's [Find](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html) class as it is specifically written for this type of task.

Comment: The CPU and RAM is not a problem, because it will only run one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the paths of all CSS files in your project, you can use this:

```
Dir.glob("./**/*.css").each do |path|
```

However I'm not sure if this will break anything or not (especially application.css). Probably a good idea to commit in git first.